# Get values from views exposed filter in hook_views_pre_view

Tags: 7, views

I would like to get the current values from an exposed filter in hook_views_pre_view().

For example, if the input filter has some value I would like to change de pager: number of items, the problem is how to get this value from views without using $_GET because I don't think it will work with views ajax.

What is the right way to get current exposed filters values from a view?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it, there is a views method:

```
$input = $view->get_exposed_input();
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution does not work as `$input` is always empty. Any ideas?